# error C2146, warning C4552, error C2059 при компиляции

Tags: c

Продолжаю учиться по самоучителю Пахомова. Задание по созданию функций. Запускаю листинг, но компиляция не удается.

```
// 13.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>             //для getchar(), putchar()
#include <conio.h>             //для getch()
#include <stdlib.h>            //для exit()
#include <locale.h>

#define eof -1                 //признак конца ввода (Ctrl+z)
#define maxline 1000           //размерность массивов (максимальная длина строк)
#define from 2                 /*константа для выделения подстроки (с этого символа
будет начинаться выделение) */
#define howmany 3              /*константа для выделения подстроки (столько символов
будет выделено) */

//-----substr (s,n,m)---------------------------------------------------------------
void substr (char v[], char s[], int n, int m)
{
    //n-й элемент находится в массиве на (n-1)-м месте
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; j=n-1; j<(n-1+m); i++, j++)
    v[i]=s[j];
    v[i]='\0';
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int getline (char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != eof && c != '\n'; i++)
        s[i]=c;
    s[i]='\0';
    i++;     //для учета количества
    return(i);
}
//--------Копирование строки в строку-----------------------------------------------
void copy (char save[], char line[])
{
    int i=0;
    while ((save[i]=line[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int _tmain()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    char s[maxline], v[maxline], w[maxline];
    printf ("Введите свою строку\n");
    int i=getline(s, maxline);
    copy(v,s);
    substr(w,v,from,howmany);
    if((i-1) < from)
    {
        printf ("Длина введенной строки не достаточна для извлечения из неё");
        getch();
        exit(0);
    }
    printf ("Введено строк = %s\n",s);
    printf ("Скопировано строк = %s\n",v);
    printf ("подстрок..... = %s\n",w);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо включить текст ошибок в вопрос (ну и на какой строке они возникают). Вряд ли кто-то сейчас пойдет гуглить, что такое `error C2146`, `warning C4552`, `error C2059`.

Comment: (21) : error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "i"
(21) : warning C4552: <: оператор не имеет результата; требуется оператор с побочным действием
(21) : error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: ;

(21) : error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: )

(22) : error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "v"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в строке

```
for (i=0; j=n-1; j<(n-1+m); i++, j++)
```

перед `j=n-1`, вместо `;` должна стоять `,`

```
for (i=0, j=n-1; j<(n-1+m); i++, j++)
```

Обычно IDE подсказывают где находится ошибка.

Comment: столько ошибок из-за одной запятой. Благодарю!